# PHP Working with Interfaces some advice needed

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have just discovered the joys of interfaces. I always knew they existed but being able to check if the class is an instanceof an interface has allowed me to add a nice amount of flexibility and the around the various objects that i'm using.

i realise that i can have any number of interfaces and i've read that it might be best to not have too many. so i'm curious as to how much i should interface.

forexample i want to add things like Interface_Images that has functions and calls for hasImages, getImages etc... that way in my views i can simply do

```
if(object instanceof Interface_Images) { 
  // do something 
} else {
  if(object->hasImages()) {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

is it worth me doing this?

Comment: imo, No need to ever test for interface or object, since this code is in a function (or method) it will be using a `type hint` i.e. `function changeImageToBePretty( Interface_Images $image) { ... `.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and use so many as you need.

Also use [is_callable](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-callable.php) for checking methods if you cannot use iterfaces.